# Correcting Run-Time Error 3554 MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am running VBA driven SQL on my MS Access form.

In this test statement, I am trying to insert `LanguageID` information based on a  `Territory_CountryID` guided by another table.

The following is my code:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest
SELECT tblCountry_Language.LanguageID
FROM tblCountry_Language
WHERE Territory_CountryID = 
    (SELECT tblTerritory_Country.Territory_CountryID 
    FROM tblTerritory_Country 
    WHERE tblTerritory_Country.TerritoryID = "& [Forms]![frmInput]![frmInput_Terms].[Form]![CountryID] &");"
```

When running the SQL, I get the runtime error 3554, saying

"At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

I understand what this error implies; a query can only have one "key" it searches by in its subquery.

Is there anything I can do if I want to return **all** of the  languages connected to the `Territory_CountryID`'s ? I.E., search based on all of the returned `Territory_CountryID`'s ?

Thanks.

Comment: The SQL `IN` keyword works wonders in `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL keyword `IN` allows you to specify a set of data as a filter criteria, either by a comma delimited list (ex: `(512, 513, 514)`) or a subquery that returns more than one value, as you have above.

Your fourth line should be changed to read as:

```
WHERE Territory_CountryID IN
```

I hope this helps.

-C§

Answer (score 0):

Why even run a subquery in `WHERE` clause when a simple `JOIN` can suffice:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest 
SELECT tblCountry_Language.LanguageID 
  FROM tblCountry_Language 
 INNER JOIN tblTerritory_Country 
    ON tblCountry_Language.Territory_CountryID = 
       tblTerritory_Country.Territory_CountryID 
 WHERE tblTerritory_Country.TerritoryID = 
       "& [Forms]![frmInput]![frmInput_Terms].[Form]![CountryID] &";"
```